# PhpStorm use import in the Sass for inheritance. Tips in IDE not worked in the TypeScript file

Tags: css, typescript, sass, phpstorm, inspection

I have 2 Sass files:

**common.module.sass**

```
.title
  color: red
...
```

**other.module.sass**

```
@import "./common.module"
...
```

I imported second file in the **other.tsx**

```
import styles from '@/styles/sprites/game-over.module.sass'
...
const smthFunc = () => {
  return <p className={styles.???}>
</p>
}
```

I can write `title` instead of `???`, but I have a lot of classes and IDE can't help me. I see tips with classes from `other.module.sass` but I don't see classes from imported files and no inspections for undefined or incorrect ClassNames.

Is it possible to fix?

I can use generic css files and all work well, maybe it's the right choice?

PhpStorm 2022.1 actual version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it's correct if write in import full file name with '.sass':

```
@import "./common.module.sass"
```